# MySQL Query and optimizing database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

I have a project i need to make for school. It's a game made in Javafx based on munchkin (board game).

We have a hero, this hero will defeat monsters in a room, and each monster defends a treasure (i'm seeing it as the monster's loot like in a mmorpg).
Now i'm not sure about the link between monsters and treasures aswell. 
**Each treasure has 0 or 1 monster. Each monster atleast has one treasure, can be multiple aswell.** 
The teacher said to use an extra table for this (Treasure_has_Monsters) in my case.
I'm not sure the references are correct though...

> **My database at the moment:**
>   [Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcAOK.jpg)

Now the problem i'm having is the following. 
I need to **get a list from all the treasures a monster has**.
And i could query the treasure_has_monster table and get all the id's of treasures
and then create a query to get all the treasures with the id's.

> **Questions:**
>
> - Is there a way to do this in one query?
> - Is the reference between Treasures and Monsters ok?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We require questioners to put the key elements of their questions directly into the question text. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting that there is a join table between monster and treasure, but not between hero and treasure.

Comment: @railsdog Yes, that's because the hero table isn't used yet. Haven't put much thought in it yet. Anyway as far as i know now there will only be one hero. We're working in iterations, making one piece at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your schema, you could try:

```
select t.* from Treasures t
join Treasures_has_Monsters tm on tm.Treasure_id=t.id
where Monster_id=?
```

where? is the monster id you want to list the treasures for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try making a simple query like:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM treasure_has_monster thm
INNER JOIN trasures t ON (thm.trasure_id = t.id)
WHERE thm.monster_id = YOUR_MONSTER_ID
```

Comment: Just beat me to it. INNER JOIN as the same as JOIN in my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. Many thanks for the fast response and help!

Answer (score 0):

No reason to join both tables together.  You could use a simple inner query.

```
SELECT * FROM Treasures
WHERE id IN (SELECT treasure_id from Treasures_has_Monsters
             WHERE monsterid = <MID>);
```

replace `<MID>` with the monster id you want to get

Comment: I think join is easier